# Magento, Extending Order Grid using XML markup method, select options issue

Tags: magento

I am looking for some an example of how to populate a select option header in Magento order grid. The following is creating the new column rendering the data and outputting a select menu in the column header. The issue is the options are not being created in the select menu.

```
<layout>
    <!-- main layout definition that adds the column -->
    <add_order_grid_column_handle>
        <reference name="sales_order.grid">
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>customer_country_id</columnId>
                <arguments module="ordermanager" translate="header">
                    <header>Shipping Country</header>
                    <index>customer_country_id</index>
                    <type>options</type>
                    <sortable>true</sortable>
                    <options>Flipmedia_AddShippingCountryColumn_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Country</options>
                    <renderer>Flipmedia_AddShippingCountryColumn_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Country</renderer>
                </arguments>
                <after>status</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </add_order_grid_column_handle>

    <!-- order grid action -->
    <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
        <!-- apply the layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="add_order_grid_column_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>

    <!-- order grid view action -->
    <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        <!-- apply the layout handle defined above -->
        <update handle="add_order_grid_column_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>



class Flipmedia_AddShippingCountryColumn_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Country extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {

    private static $_countryList = array();

    public function options(Varien_Object $row) {
         if (count(self::$_countryList) == 0) {          
            $countries =        Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
                                    ->loadData()
                                    ->toOptionArray(false);
            foreach ($countries as $country) {
                self::$_countryList[$country['value']] = $country['label'];
            }
         }

         return self::$_countryList;
     }

    public function render(Varien_Object $row){
           $value = $this->_getValue($row);        
           $_countryList = $this->options();           
           return isset($_countryList[$value]) ? $_countryList[$value] : false;
        }
}
```

Comment: `customer_country_id` is not a column of `sales_flat_order_grid`: have you added it? Also, paste the code of >Flipmedia_AddShippingCountryColumn_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Country` so we can check if there is something wrong with it

Comment: The above is only a snippet of the overall extension, there is an install script that adds the column and populates from existing data and an observer that populates this new column as orders are created. My questions relates specifically to the header filter aspect this was answered perfectly by CCBlackburn. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your `<options>` element, if you override the sales order grid by rewriting it, you have to specify a static function for the options. I've had a look around and it looks like you need to change the way you invoke this.

Instead of using the `<options>` element, can you try a `<filter>` element like

```
<filter>Flipmedia_AddShippingCountryColumn_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Country</filter>
```

Note the new class, it should extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Select` like this...check out [the magento svn](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Backup/Grid/Filter/Type.php) as a reference.

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Grid_Filter_Inventory extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Select
{

    protected function _getOptions()
    {
        // return an array of options
        return array(
                array(
                'value' =>  '',
                'label' =>  ''
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't get a chance to try it out, glad it worked out for you