# Adding a search field to the Magento admin

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.7, magento

Is there a way to add a new search field in the Magento admin under "Orders"? I want to be able to search by coupon code usage (ex: search by coupon code: "sale2013", come up with all the orders that applied that coupon code during checkout).

[image]

I'm able to pull this data out of the Magento DB, but I'd really like to add this functionality to the Magento admin to make it easier for co-workers and my boss. Can it be done and, if so, ideas as to where I can start? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The coupon code used during checkout is stored on the primary order table (`sales_flat_order`) when the customer checks out. If there is no value, then no coupon code was used. However, the data for the grid in the admin comes from the `sales_flat_order_grid` table; it comes from there instead of the primary order table for performance reasons which become particularly evident on very high traffic sites.

Now that we know where the data is that you need to filter on, and where the data for the grid comes from, we can move on to build it!

The first thing that you will need to do is add a `coupon_code` column to the `sales_flat_order_grid` table matching the definition of the column on the `sales_flat_order` table. The values in the `coupon_code` column of `sales_flat_order` should automatically populate into `sales_flat_order_grid` once the matching column is there and your cache storage has been flushed.

The data is updated on the order save, so to be specific, new orders and orders updated via the admin (even a comment on the order) will have the data populated. For existing orders, run a data upgrade script to copy the values over.

After the data/schemas are in place, you'll want to have the grid show a filterable column for it. For this you will want to rewrite the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` class from your custom module (please don't edit the core files directly, it will haunt you later) and override the `_prepareColumns` method with one that includes your column definition:

```
    $this->addColumn('coupon_code', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Coupon Code'),
        'index' => 'coupon_code',
    ));
```

If you're very fresh on Magento development, I'd venture to say that I've only begun to help you. But you'll have plenty of reference points from which to dig in and build the functionality you need. HTH! :)

Comment: there is an event for every grid you can use. No rewrite needed.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, there is no event fired from `_prepareColumns`. Which event did you have in mind?

Comment: you are right. there is no event, (TIL) but you can call addColumnAfter from the layout file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367516/magento-extending-order-grid-using-xml-markup-method-select-options-issue

Answer (score 0):

Adding new columns to a grid is easy with this extension:
https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl

Add this extension, write your own with a `gridcontrol.xml` inside your etc directory

And then something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gridcontrol>
<grids>
    <order.grid>
        <coupon_code>
            <after>columnname</after>

            <add>
                <header>Coupon code</header>
                <type>text</type>
                <index>coupon_code</index>
                <joinField>coupon_code|sales/order|coupon_code|entity_id=entity_id||left</joinField>
            </add>
        </coupon_code>
    </order.grid>
</grids>
</gridcontrol>
```

Comment: This is IMO a poor solution because it will in the long run hamper performance. One should not be joining values onto the sales order grid which was very intentionally setup to run on a single flat table (with no joins) for the purpose of maintaining performance.

Comment: good point, but on both entity_id columns are indexes, I don't think this is a big problem @davidalger